# Не могу вызвать метод

Tags: java

Только начинаю изучать Java и не понимаю, почему не могу вызвать метод zeroToOne к переменной i. Не появляется в контекстном меню IDE. Какая здесь ошибка?

```
public class Method {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        **i.zeroToOne();**
    }

    private int zeroToOne (int a) {
        if (a == 0) {
            a = 1;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zeroToOne(i);` - так делается вызов. В Java прямолинейная система вызовов, что указано параметром, то передается аргументом.

И поскольку метод `main` статический, то вызывать `zeroToOne` нужно на объекте: `new Method().zeroToOne(i);`. Либо делать статическим метод `zeroToOne` (`private static int zeroToOne (int a)`) и вызывать напрямую, а не через объект.